# Visual Studio: Теряются закладки в проекте

Tags: visual-studio

По роду своей деятельности приходиться работать на двух ПК, на каждом установлен Visual Studio 2017. Проект хранится на сервере. Если в проект добавить закладки (Bookmark) с одного ПК, то при открытии проекта на другом ПК закладки теряются. Пробовал с VS2019 - проблема сохраняется. Буду благодарен за любые идеи.

Comment: Вы открываете проект прямо на сетевом диске на файл-сервере? Или копируете к себе? Или как-то еще? Закладки хранятся не в проекте, а в `.suo` файле в скрытой директории `.vs`.

Comment: Пробовал открывать и на сетевом диске и копировать к себе - не помогает. Проверил, .suo файлы тоже копируются.

Comment: Причем экземпляр VS в котором создавались закладки их видит, а VS на другом ПК - нет.

Answer (score 1):

Порылся на форумах Microsoft и наткнулся на дельную мысль: Закладки проекта VS хранят прямой путь к файлам, а не относительный. Расположил проект на разных ПК в папки с одинаковыми путями (например: D:\Project\AvZvk) и проблема исчезла.